# How to analyze a discretely measured DV over time with complex pattern?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, nonlinear-regression

I have data on a randomized study.

Patients were randomly assigned to treatment and control; there were a total of only 25 patients.. Each patient had 2 surgeries, the randomization was for treatment after the surgery.  Each patient was measured at 7 time points on several measures.  All the measures are ordinal level (0, 1, 2, 3, or 4).  The time points are baseline, 3 days after 1st surgery, 7 days after 1st surgery, 30 days after 1st surgery, 3 days after 2nd surgery, 30 days after 2nd, and 90 days after treatment 2.

It is expected that symptoms will get worse after each surgery, then better.  Interest is in whether there were differences between treatment and control at any time point and whether those differences persisted over time.

I think some sort of nonlinear multilevel model is appropriate, but am not sure of the best way to deal with the two surgeries, which will make the expected trajectories complex.

Perhaps 2 analyses, one for the 1st surgery and another for the 2nd?  Or maybe something with a spline fit? Or some other approach?

If it matters, I have SAS and R available.

Comment: I am from a very different community, so this may be a silly suggestion ... but could you try to estimate linear Markov transition matrices over the ordinal measures between time snapshots? Then you could compare matrices estimated from the aggregated data, vs. estimated from data stratified by treatments? (Sort of a null model for "expected trajectory".)

Comment: That's a very interesting idea.  But .... I have no idea how to do it. I may suggest it to my client, though.